# Can we calculate $E[Y|Z]$ if we know $f(Y|X)$ and $f(X|Z)$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

While reading [Jennifer Hill (2011)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jcgs.2010.08162?journalCode=ucgs20), p. 220, in the context of conditional average treatment effect, the author is able to calculate $E[Y|Z]$ from $f(Y|X)$ and $f(X|Z)$.

My attempt to replicate the author's calculation is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
E[Y|Z] &= \int y f(y|z) dy \\
&= \int y \int f(y, x| z) dx dy \\
&= \int y \int f(y|x, z) f(x|z) dx dy\\
&= \int y \int f(y|x) f(x|z) dx dy
\end{align}
$$

where the last equation is true because $y$ is independent from $z$ once conditional on $x$.

However, this integration is rather nightmarish even with the Gaussian distributions, i.e. $f(x|z=1) \sim N(40, 10^2)$ and $f(y|x) = N(72 + 3 \sqrt x, 1)$. I tried Mathematica, which couldn't give the numerical result either.

Is this the correct approach to calculate $E[Y|Z]$, or there is a more sensible approach?

Comment: So you occasionally get complex means for $y$?

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from your last statement, we have
$$ \int_y y \int_x f(y|x) f(x|z) dx dy $$
$$ =\int_x\left[\int_y y  f(y|x) dy \right] f(x|z) dx $$
$$ =\int_x E[Y|X] f(x|z) dx $$
and that's it.

But, if by any chance everything is Gaussian, then 
$$E[Y|X]=E[Y]+\alpha (X-E[X])$$
where $\alpha=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{var(X)}$. So we have
$$ = \int_x \left[ \mu_Y + \alpha x -\alpha \mu_X \right] f(x|z) dx $$
$$ = \mu_Y -\alpha \mu_X + \alpha \int_x x f(x|z) dx $$
$$ = \mu_Y -\alpha \mu_X + \alpha E[X|Z]$$
which can be expressed easily using the same method, if it is Gaussian.

Comment: How does $X$ and $Y$ being normal lead to that way of calculating $E[Y|X]$? I think that's only true when $X, Y$ are bivariate normal.

Comment: You're right, by 'everything' I meant they're jointly normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using $\int_x E[Y|X] f(x|z) dx$ Mathematica did manage to give the definite integral this time. Is it because we've simplified the integral?

Comment: Well, I don't know how Mathematica works, but consider that switching the integral order does require some assumptions, so the algorithm might not have wanted to do that on its own.